# Partitions of a set into three parts

Tags: discrete-mathematics, set-partition

How many partitions of the set $\{1,2,3, \ldots , 100\}$ are there such that both

a) there are exactly three parts and

b) elements $1,2,3$ are in different parts.

Any help on this question would be fine. Hints are welcomed

Comment: This might be useful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set#Counting_partitions

Answer (score 1):

Since there are exactly three parts and elements $1,2,3$ are in different parts, you may as well call the parts they are each in "Part $1$", "Part $2$" and "Part $3$" respectively.

Each of the remaining $100-3=97$ parts can be in any of these three parts, meaning that there are $3^{97}$ partitions which meet your conditions.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** It's the same as the three times the number of ways to partition the set $\{4,5, \dots, 100\}$ into three different parts where as many as two of the parts are allowed to be empty (can you see why?), and a formula for the latter value exists (specifically, you should look into Stirling numbers of the second kind and modify the count to account for the possibly-empty sets).

Comment: so using the sterling numbers of the second kind, would it be written as S(97,3)?

Comment: No, not Stirling numbers of the second kind, as the parts are labelled $1,2,3$.